# Cannot execute pip, even with correct permissions

Tags: permissions, python, pip

I am looking to run `pip` that is located in a `conda` environment here:

```
/opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin
```

After activating the conda environment and running pip:

```
$ conda activate myenv
$ pip --help
```

I receive the following errors:

```
bash: /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/pip: /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

The permissions on /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/pip are:

```
 File: /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/pip
  Size: 234         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 66h/102d    Inode: 10355178    Links: 1
Access: (0770/-rwxrwx---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1000/anaconda)
Access: 2019-12-03 20:15:28.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2019-12-03 20:15:28.000000000 +0000
Change: 2019-12-03 20:20:01.754106880 +0000
 Birth: -
```

The permissions on /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/python are:

```
  File: python -> python3.7
  Size: 9           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 3dh/61d Inode: 10355190    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1000/anaconda)
Access: 2019-12-03 20:15:42.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2019-12-03 20:15:42.000000000 +0000
Change: 2019-12-03 20:20:01.758106820 +0000
 Birth: -
```

I've also verified my user (`myuser`) is in the `anaconda` group with:

```
$ cat /etc/group
anaconda:x:1000:root,myuser
```

I even try to provide it with the absolute path and it still fails:

```
$ /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/pip --help
bash: /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/pip: /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Why can't I run `pip`, even though I have the correct permissions?  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you changed the `python` symlink to point to `python3.7` instead of `python2`.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/994198/cannot-execute-pip-even-with-correct-permissions) question. Please don't ask identical questions on multiple sites.

Comment: Sorry I realized that server fault may not have been the correct stack exchange site to post it on.

Comment: @user535733 My conda environment (`myenv`) has `python3.7` installed (uses hardlink for this I believe).  Also, where did you get `python2` from?